# Limited number of break lines in text in PHP

Tags: php

Assume a string is like

```
Section 1

Section 2 (after 1 line break)


Section 3 (after 2 line breaks)




Section 4 (after 4 line breaks)

Section 5 (after 1 line break)
```

My intention is to only allow N number of breaks and replace the other ones with SPACE in PHP. For example, if N=3 then the text above would be outputed like:

```
Section 1

Section 2 (after 1 line break)

Section 3 (after 2 line breaks) Section 4 (after 4 line breaks) Section 5 (after 1 line break)
```

My code is below but I am looking for a better way:

```
function limitedBreaks($str = '', $n = 5)
{
    $str = nl2br($str);
    $chars = str_split($str);
    $counter = 0;
    foreach ($chars as $key => $char) {
        if ($char == "<br/>")
            if ($counter > $n) {
                $chars[$key] = ' ';
            } else {
                $counter += 1;
            }
    }

    return implode($chars, ' ');

}
```

Comment: `explode("\n", $str, $n);` and replace \n to space in the last item

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This really is a job better suited for regex than exploding and iterating.

```
$str = preg_replace('~\v+~', "\n\n", $str);
```

Here `\v+` matches any number of vertical spaces, substituted with two `\n` newlines. You will get a standard one line gap between your content (non-linebreak-only) lines. This results in:

```
Section 1

Section 2 (after 1 line break)

Section 3 (after 2 line breaks)

Section 4 (after 4 line breaks)

Section 5 (after 1 line break)
```

If you want to only target more than N breaks, use e.g. `\v{4,}`, assuming EOL is `\n`, to normalize all instances of 4 or more newlines. If your file uses Windows EOL (`\r\n`), be aware that you need to double it up, or use `(\r\n|\n){4,}`, since `\r` and `\n` each are one match of `\v`.

That's the basic idea. Seeing as you want to replace 4+ newlines with horizontal space, merging the lines instead of normalizing line break quantity, you would simply:

```
$str = preg_replace('~(\r\n|\n){4,}~', " ", $str);
```

This would give you:

```
Section 1

Section 2 (after 1 line break)


Section 3 (after 2 line breaks) Section 4 (after 4 line breaks)

Section 5 (after 1 line break)
```

Here the gap with 4 or more EOLs was substituted with space and merged with the preceding line. The rest of the "acceptably spaced" lines are still in their places.

---

However it seems that you want to merge *all subsequent rows into a single line* after any gap of 4+ EOLs. Is that really the requirement? The first example I posted is a fairly standard operation for normalizing content with irregular linebreaks; especially "level items" like section headings!

---

OP: thanks for explaining your use case, makes sense. This can be regex-ed without loops:

```
$str = preg_replace_callback('~(\r\n|\n){4,}(?<therest>.+)~s', function($match) {
    return ' ' . preg_replace('~\v+~', ' ', $match['therest']);
}, $str);
```

Here we capture (as named group `therest`) all the content that follows four or more linebreaks using `preg_replace_callback`, and inside the callback we `preg_replace` all vertical spaces in "the rest" with a single horizontal space. This results in:

```
Section 1

Section 2 (after 1 line break)


Section 3 (after 2 line breaks) Section 4 (after 4 line breaks) Section 5 (after 1 line break) Section 17 after a hundred bundred line breaks"
```

For convenience, here's the regex above wrapped in a function:

```
function fuse_breaks(string $str): string {
    $str = preg_replace_callback('~(\r\n|\n){4,}(?<therest>.+)~s', function($match) {
        return ' ' . preg_replace('~\v+~', ' ', $match['therest']);
    }, $str);
    return $str;
}

// Usage:
$fused_text = fuse_breaks($source_text);
```

Comment: Hi Yes the goal is to make a single line after a specific number of EOL. In fact, I want to prevent a page attack that someone posts a text with a lot of EOL and blocks other posts in the forum.

Comment: Alright, thanks for explaining your use case. Makes sense, I've seen that happening. Have added in a regex that does just that.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to reproduce the results above in https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/ however, I cannot even after `$str = str_replace("\r","",$str)` because I am on windows.

Comment: I am also on Windows. There is no need to normalize `\r`, the regex above is already platform-agnostic. I can't tell what's going on in your sandbox because it doesn't show what you tried. Please see in action what I posted here: https://3v4l.org/udVNH .... and it works as expected also on your sandbox site (defaulting to PHP 7.2?!). Note that I turned the regex into function at the link -- just to have the actual code visible at the top. If it doesn't work, please share a live example with actual code and source string tested with.

Answer (score 1):

Your example with N=3 shows either 4 line breaks – if the empty lines count –, or 2 line breaks.

To make things clearer this is a function *limitedLines*, which reduces the text to a specific amount of lines:

```
$str = "
line 1 
line 2
line 3
line 4
line 5
line 6
";

function limitedLines(string $str = '', int $maxLines = 5): string {
  $maxLines = $maxLines < 1 ? 1 : $maxLines;
  $arr = explode("\n", trim($str));
  while (count($arr) > $maxLines) {
    $last = array_pop($arr);
    $arr[array_key_last($arr)] .= ' ' . trim($last);
  }
  return implode("\n", $arr);
}

$result = limitedLines($str, 3);

print_r($result);
```

This will print:

```
line 1 
line 2
line 3 line 4 line 5 line 6
```

Comment: Thanks. However, this does not give me the same result as in your example. Please try it here https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/

Comment: The link is not valid (or rather the code shown is not the correct one).

Comment: Thanks again. yes, the website does not allow sharing code. It is for testing only.

Comment: I copy pasted the code, executed it, and I get the result as listed above. Can you say what differences you get?

Comment: that is weird. I get line 4 5 6 in new lines

Comment: Yes, that's weird. Are you on an older PHP version than say 8 ?

Comment: I tested that with 8 and 7.4 and the same. I checked and it seems a windows thing (\r) that needs to be replaced with blank

Comment: I'm not on Windows. Glad you figured it out.

Comment: Explode really isn't the tool for matching line breaks unless you normalize `\r` out first and then explode by `\n`, given it's hard to control what sort of data may land in your function from different platforms.